# Lazy loading different images from a random image url fails in vue js

Tags: html, vue.js

I have this code that lazy loads images

```
<img src="https://source.unsplash.com/1600x900/?hotel,booking.com?v=1" loading="lazy" />
<img src="https://source.unsplash.com/1600x900/?hotel,booking.com?v=2" loading="lazy" />
<img src="https://source.unsplash.com/1600x900/?hotel,booking.com?v=3" loading="lazy" />
<img src="https://source.unsplash.com/1600x900/?hotel,booking.com?v=4" loading="lazy" />
```

and this is how it looks like https://jsfiddle.net/pg968ntz/

The image url should load a new image everytime its refreshed or loaded. I have used lazy loading to make that happen and it works in plain html.

However, using the same code inside a vue js template results in the same image being loaded. I have tried even binding a variable `<img :src="image_link" width="200" height="200" loading="lazy" />`

but still loads the same image four times instead of a different image four times. Is there a way i can fix this to load four different images inside of a vue js template?

Comment: Why don't you use v-for?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do like this.
Please confirm this URL https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-wvu8sm?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FHelloWorld.vue

```
  <template>
      <img v-for="(image, index) in images" :key="index"  :src="image" width="200" height="200" loading="lazy" />
  </template>

    export default {
      data() {
            return {
              images: [
                "https://source.unsplash.com/1600x900/?hotel,booking.com?v=1",
                "https://source.unsplash.com/1600x900/?hotel,booking.com?v=2",
                "https://source.unsplash.com/1600x900/?hotel,booking.com?v=3",
                "https://source.unsplash.com/1600x900/?hotel,booking.com?v=4",                
              ]
            };
       }
     }
```

Comment: Still the same. The images array should contain only one item since its the same random url fetching the image.

Comment: Do you know about that API? I think it sometimes return same images.

Comment: Sometimes different images are loaded.